# asp.net AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox: How do I change the Mouse over color of the List Items in CSS?

Tags: asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, highlight

I found some blogs that show how to override the default ItemList style like this:
        .CustomComboBoxStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist li {
             background-color: Green;
             border: 1px solid YellowGreen;
             color: White;
             font-size:medium;
             font-family:Courier New;
             padding-bottom: 5px;
         }

I was hoping I could do something like this to change the default MouseOver color:
        .cbStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist li:hover
        {
         color:Lime;
        }

but this has no effect.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
- Paul

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET server controls render their own id concatenated with your original id. So if you want to style a control you would use something like `$ct100_combobox_myComboBoxId`. Just right click the source to see what the server rendered for the id.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft added a new feature in .NET 4.0 to create predictable/customizable client side IDs from server-side controls. [Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/07/01/extending-client-side-programming-in-aspnet-4.aspx) (Controlling the ClientId section)